# What is the maximum value of the inner product of a unit vector and another vector in the same subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

My guess, was it would be the infinity norm, but I feel like I am completely wrong.

Answer (score 12):

$$\max_{u : \|u\|=1} \langle u,v\rangle = \|v\|.$$
Cauchy-Schwarz proves the maximum is $\le \|v\|$, and taking $u=v/\|v\|$ shows that the maximum is precisely $\|v\|$.

Comment: What is this result called in a broader context (I am thinking Hilbert spaces)? Where can I find more info on it?

Comment: @plebmatician Not quite sure you are asking for, but [dual norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_norm#Mathematical_Optimization) and Hölder's inequality may be relevant for you

Answer (score 1):

In a space $\mathbb R^n$, the inner product between $v$ and $u$ is given by $|u| \cdot |v| \cos \theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle between vectors $v$ and $u$.

The maximum value is attained when $\theta = 0$-- when $u$ and $v$ point in the same direction (and are consequently in the same subspace, no matter which subspace you've chosen). The value is equal to $|u| \cdot |v|$ which is equal to the magnitude of the non-unit vector.