# What is the maximum of the inner product on the unit sphere?

Tags: proof-writing, inner-products

This quesiton has already been asked for the simple $\mathbb{R}^n$ vector space [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2548285/what-is-the-maximum-value-of-the-inner-product-of-a-unit-vector-and-another-vect).
I however would like to have a general proof for the following:

Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $F$, i.e. we have:

1. $\langle\cdot,\cdot \rangle: V\times V \rightarrow F$
2. $\langle x,y\rangle =\overline{\langle y,x\rangle}$
3. $\langle \alpha x,y\rangle =\alpha \langle x,y\rangle$
4. $\langle x+y,z\rangle = \langle x,z\rangle +\langle y,z\rangle$
5. $\langle x,x\rangle \geq 0$, $\langle x,x\rangle=0\Leftrightarrow x = 0$

Let $B_1(V)$ be the unit sphere of $V$ (with respect to $\langle \cdot ,\cdot \rangle$)

Now to the actual question:

Let $v\in B_1(V)$. Show that 
$$\sup_{w\in B_1(V)} |\langle v,w\rangle| = 1.$$

Optimally the proof would be built on the axioms itself, i.e. without the use of advanced theorems.

Comment: Is $F$ an arbitrary field? If so, how are you defining $\overline{\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle}$ and $|\cdot|$?

Comment: @Bungo Haven't thought about that. Optimally some version of this theorem is true for all fields. However if this is not possible let's just take $F = \mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: [This question and the answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1066176/why-are-every-structures-i-study-based-on-real-number?noredirect=1&lq=1) could also help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take $\mathbb{F}$ as the real or complex fields, then
it can be shown that any inner product satisfies the Cauchy-Scwartz inequality, namely:

$$|\langle u,v\rangle|\leq \|u\| \|v\|$$
for every $u,v$, where $\|u\|=\sqrt{\langle u,u\rangle}$

Now it follows immediately from the C-S inequality that given $v\in B_1(V)$, for every
$w\in B_1(V)$ you have $|\langle w,v\rangle|\leq 1$, and if $v\neq 0$, you can take
$w=\frac{v}{\|v\|}$, so that the supremum is actually a maximum.